# Check how many entries are in table by date

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

Im trying to create a specific query. 
E.g
i have table with events:

```
id |     start        |      end
-----------------------------------------
1  | 10-08-2013 12:00 | 10-08-2013  14:00
2  | 10-08-2013 12:00 | 10-08-2013  14:00
3  | 10-08-2013 15:00 | 10-08-2013  16:00
```

And i want to insert a new `event( start: 13:00, end: 15:30 )` and before that i want to check by query how many events are on the same time. In this case results should be 3: beacause 2 events are in start time and one is on the end time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ID) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
WHERE   new_startDate BETWEEN start AND end 
        OR
        new_endDate BETWEEN start AND end
```

where `new_startDate` and `new_endDate` are the new dates of the event.

Comment: I think @Gordon's answer is what the OP wants. This will return `0` if `new_startDate` is `11:00` and `new_endDate` is 20:00.

Answer (score 4):

The correct logic for overlap is:

```
where new_startDate <= end and
      new_endDate >= start
```